# Capistrano/RVM rake not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, capistrano

I'm trying to deploy the first rails application using Capistrano.

I'm getting an error while capistrano tries to run `rake db:migrate`.
To be more clear this is the traceback of the exception:

```
[ip] executing command
*** [err :: ip] bash: rake: command not found
command finished in 124ms
failed: "env RAILS_ENV=production bash -c 'cd /home/deployer/website/current && rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate'" on ip
```

And this is the `config/deploy.rb` I'm using actually. On the server I've installed RVM (single user installation).

```
# config/deploy.rb 
$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path']))

require "rvm/capistrano"

set :scm,             :git
set :repository,      "git@bitbucket.org:user/project.git"
set :branch,          "origin/master"
set :migrate_target,  :current
set :ssh_options,     { :forward_agent => true }
set :rails_env,       "production"
set :deploy_to,       "/home/deployer/website"
set :normalize_asset_timestamps, false
set :rvm_type, :user  # Don't use system-wide RVM
set :rvm_ruby_string, "ruby-1.9.3-p194@global"

set :user,            "deployer"
set :group,           "staff"
set :use_sudo,        false

role :web,    "IP"
role :app,    "IP"
role :db,     "IP2", :primary => true

set(:latest_release)  { fetch(:current_path) }
set(:release_path)    { fetch(:current_path) }
set(:current_release) { fetch(:current_path) }

set(:current_revision)  { capture("cd #{current_path}; git rev-parse --short HEAD").strip }
set(:latest_revision)   { capture("cd #{current_path}; git rev-parse --short HEAD").strip }
set(:previous_revision) { capture("cd #{current_path}; git rev-parse --short HEAD@{1}").strip }

default_environment["RAILS_ENV"] = 'production'

default_run_options[:shell] = 'bash'

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Deploy your application"
  task :default do
    update
    restart
  end

  desc "Setup your git-based deployment app"
  task :setup, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    dirs = [deploy_to, shared_path]
    dirs += shared_children.map { |d| File.join(shared_path, d) }
    run "#{try_sudo} mkdir -p #{dirs.join(' ')} && #{try_sudo} chmod g+w #{dirs.join(' ')}"
    run "git clone #{repository} #{current_path}"
  end

  task :cold do
    update
    migrate
  end

  task :update do
    transaction do
      update_code
    end
  end

  desc "Update the deployed code."
  task :update_code, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "cd #{current_path}; git fetch origin; git reset --hard #{branch}"
    finalize_update
  end

  desc "Update the database (overwritten to avoid symlink)"
  task :migrations do
    transaction do
      update_code
    end
    migrate
    restart
  end

  task :finalize_update, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "chmod -R g+w #{latest_release}" if fetch(:group_writable, true)

    # mkdir -p is making sure that the directories are there for some SCM's that don't
    # save empty folders
    run <<-CMD
      rm -rf #{latest_release}/log #{latest_release}/public/system #{latest_release}/tmp/pids &&
      mkdir -p #{latest_release}/public &&
      mkdir -p #{latest_release}/tmp &&
      ln -s #{shared_path}/log #{latest_release}/log &&
      ln -s #{shared_path}/system #{latest_release}/public/system &&
      ln -s #{shared_path}/pids #{latest_release}/tmp/pids &&
      ln -sf #{shared_path}/database.yml #{latest_release}/config/database.yml
    CMD

    if fetch(:normalize_asset_timestamps, true)
      stamp = Time.now.utc.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M.%S")
      asset_paths = fetch(:public_children, %w(images stylesheets javascripts)).map { |p| "#{latest_release}/public/#{p}" }.join(" ")
      run "find #{asset_paths} -exec touch -t #{stamp} {} ';'; true", :env => { "TZ" => "UTC" }
    end
  end

  desc "Zero-downtime restart of Unicorn"
  task :restart, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "kill -s USR2 `cat /tmp/unicorn.my_site.pid`"
  end

  desc "Start unicorn"
  task :start, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "cd #{current_path} ; bundle exec unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.rb -D"
  end

  desc "Stop unicorn"
  task :stop, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "kill -s QUIT `cat /tmp/unicorn.my_site.pid`"
  end  

  namespace :rollback do
    desc "Moves the repo back to the previous version of HEAD"
    task :repo, :except => { :no_release => true } do
      set :branch, "HEAD@{1}"
      deploy.default
    end

    desc "Rewrite reflog so HEAD@{1} will continue to point to at the next previous release."
    task :cleanup, :except => { :no_release => true } do
      run "cd #{current_path}; git reflog delete --rewrite HEAD@{1}; git reflog delete --rewrite HEAD@{1}"
    end

    desc "Rolls back to the previously deployed version."
    task :default do
      rollback.repo
      rollback.cleanup
    end
  end
end

def run_rake(cmd)
  run "cd #{current_path}; #{rake} #{cmd}"
end
```

How can I make this run properly?

Of course I already tried to run `rake` on the server, and it is found properly.

Thanks

Comment: also make sure you remove `$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path']))` as the message should warn you already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you break `rvm/capistrano` integration by adding this line:

```
default_run_options[:shell] = 'bash'
```

You need to remove it.

Also I see a lot of over-engineering in your script, please check my example script which I run from time to time to confirm RVM works as expected:
https://github.com/mpapis/ad/blob/master/config/deploy.rb

Comment: I downloaded it from a tutorial online since it's the 1st time I ever run capistrano. I like your script, it seems much simpler (and I like it). I was scared by have to write each time all that file from scratch... Maybe it could take less lines to do it using plain scp, git and remote shell.